# How can I test that an imported Perl 6 routine exists?

Tags: testing, import, raku

I want to check that an exportable subroutine isn't defined in the current scope, and I also want to test that a subroutine isn't defined. Both of these should happen without running the code and I'd really like a way to do it without an `EVAL`. The examples I found in the roast executed the subroutines that the testers assumed were already there.

Here's what I cobbled together, but it's mostly unsatisfying for a language where I expect to be able to inspect things:

```
use Test;

module Foo {
    sub this-exists    is export { say "This exists"; return 1 }
    sub this-is-a-stub is export { !!! }
    sub this-is-a-todo is export { ... }
    sub not-exported             { say "Not exported" }
    }

import Foo;  # https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/359

# Is the class there?
 ok ::("Foo") !~~ Failure, "module Foo is defined";
 ok ::("Bar") ~~ Failure, "module Bar is not defined";

# this should work, but note the first one compiles because it works.
# if the routine isn't there, the &some-name is a compilation error.
 ok &this-exists,   "this-exists is there";
 ok &("not-there"), "this-exists is there";

# these are exported but they aren't "defined" because they
# are stubs. How is this supposed to work?
dies-ok { EVAL Q/&this-is-a-stub/ }, "this-is-a-stub is not defined";
nok &("this-is-a-stub"), "this-is-a-stub is not defined";
nok &("this-is-a-todo"), "this-is-a-todo is not defined";

# these shouldn't be defined here
dies-ok { EVAL Q/ &not-exported / }, "not-exported is not defined";
dies-ok { EVAL Q/ &not-there /    }, "not-there is not defined";

done-testing();
```

Answer (score 4):

```perl6
say so ::('&non-existent'); # False

say so ::('&say'); # True

if ::('&say') -> &say {
  say 4; # 4␤
}
```

Note that these also work to reference a subroutine that may or may not exist.

```perl6
&::('say')
::{'&say','&put'}
::<&say &put>     # similar to previous line

&CORE::('say')
CORE::('&say')
CORE::{'&say','&put'}
CORE::<&say &put> # similar to previous line
```

Also `&(…)` is for coercing something to a code type object, so only works on things that are already a `Callable` or have a `CALL-ME` method.

Comment: So, in my &("this-is-a-stub") example, it's either Callable or has the CALL-ME, but Perl 6 doesn't know what's on the inside. I recall reading that the metamodel knew if a _method_ had `!!!` on the inside.

Comment: @briandfoy It does know what is on the inside, it is a Str. `&('foo' but role { method CALL-ME (){ say 'called' }})()` I think `&()` is really only useful for turning an expression into an infix operator `1 [&(*+*)] 2` or `[[&(*+*)]] 1,2,3`

Comment: I meant, the code _inside_ the named method. It knows if it's a stub or not.

Comment: @briandfoy `&::('foo').yada` returns True if it is a stub